# How to display timestamp in Android Notifications for Honeycomb+ devices?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'd like to show a timestamp in an Android Notification, just like the [Android Design Guidelines suggest.](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html) (see the first snapshot, "12:03PM" is what I want!).

I tried many different ways, I thought `setWhen` would do it, but it only seems to affect the ordering in the Notification tray. Any idea how to achieve that?

See my code below:

```
  Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);
  builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify)
    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
    .setTicker(text)
    .setNumber(unreadCount)
    .setWhen((new Date()).getTime())
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .setContentTitle(title)
    .setContentText(text)
    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);

notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.getNotification());
```

I don't want to use a custom layout for the notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the answer myself, `when` seems to be displayed only on Android 4.0.**3** and later.
My wife's Nexus S (4.0.3) shows it, and I just upgraded to 4.0.**4** on my Galaxy Nexus and it magically started to work!

It also shows on older versions (2.3 for instance), but not on 4.0.**2** !

Answer (score 0):

Use `setContentInfo` and pass your date as a string into it.

From [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setContentInfo%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) link

> public Notification.Builder setContentInfo (CharSequence info) Since: API Level 11
>
> Set the large text at the right-hand side of the notification.

Large Text at the right hand side of the notification should be where you want to put time.

Also from the same link:

> public Notification.Builder setWhen (long when) Since: API Level 11
>
> Set the time that the event occurred. Notifications in the panel are
>   sorted by this time.

which means that `setWhen` only sorts the notifications, and doesn't set any text.

Comment: It does not seem to work. `setContentInfo` will display the string on line 2, replacing `number`. What I want is `when` on the right of line 1, and `number` on the right of line 2.
The funny thing is that they use GTalk and Calendar notifications as example, and none of these apps show a timestamp on my Galaxy Nexus (4.0.2).